# Printing video duration information using ffmpeg in perl

Tags: perl, time, ffmpeg, duration

Hi
I am trying to get a video duration and insert in into the database with the video. 
But now I am working with extracting video duration using ffmpeg. 
I am working on this for past 1 week. 
I am able to make this work in linux. 
But in windows its just not able to print the duration. 
Here is the code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Open3;

my @list = glob('*.mp3 *.mp4 *.mpg *.aac *.midi *m3u *.mpa *.dat *.avi');

foreach my $song (@list){

print "$song \n";

my $filename = $song;

my %videoInfo = videoInfo($filename);
print "duration: " . $videoInfo{'duration'}. "\n";
print "durationsecs: " . $videoInfo{'durationsecs'}. "\n\n";

}

sub videoInfo {

# ffmpeg command

my $ffmpeg = 'C:\ffmpeg.exe';



my %finfo = (

              'duration'     => "00:00:00.00",
              'durationsecs'  => "0"
);

my $file = shift;



# escaping characters

$file =~ s/(\W)/$1/g;



open3( "nul", "nul", \*ERPH, "$ffmpeg -i $file" ) or die "can't run $ffmpeg\n";

my @res = <ERPH>;

foreach (@res) {



     #duration

    if (m!Duration: ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9])!) {

        $finfo{'duration'} = $1;

    }

 }


my $tenths  = substr( $finfo{'duration'}, 9, 2 );


my $seconds = substr( $finfo{'duration'}, 6, 2 );

my $minutes = substr( $finfo{'duration'}, 3, 2 );

my $hours   = substr( $finfo{'duration'}, 0, 2 );

$finfo{'durationsecs'} = ( $tenths * .01 ) + $seconds + ( $minutes * 60 ) + ( $hours * 360 );

return %finfo;
}
```

I installed ffmpeg in C:\ and given the path.

ffmpeg is working fine and is displaying bitrate, codec  etc etc ( Here I have removed it since I only need Duration) But its jus not printing any duration, Its just printing 00:00:00.00.

I suspect its the search problem in the array.

Please help me in getting through this..

Here is the ouput when I run ffmpeg from command prompt

```
C:\>ffmpeg.exe -i cisco1.flv
FFmpeg version Sherpya-r10707, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
libavutil version: 49.5.0
libavcodec version: 51.45.0
libavformat version: 51.14.0
built on Oct 11 2007 06:25:25, gcc: 4.2.1 [Sherpya]
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cisco1.flv':
Duration: 00:08:37.0, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 421 kb/s
Stream #0.0(und): Audio: mpeg4aac, 44100 Hz, stereo
Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 960x720, 29.97 fps(r)
Must supply at least one output file
```

Here you can see the duration is fine.

If I add a

```
print;
```

Statement in the above code below line

```
foreach (@res) {
```

It will display the same ffmpeg output

Comment: please post a sample of the output of the `$ffmpeg` command when you run it normally on the command line.

Comment: when I execute the above script exactly it just prints me this cisco2.mp4
duration: 00:00:00.00
durationsecs: 0    That is  it automatically detects the videos in current folder and prints its duration. But its printing 00:00:00.00   the durationsecs is not important for me,  If you add a print;  after the line foreach (@res) {
you can see the actual output from ffmpeg which shows the duration perfectly. But I am not able to search the array and print it.

Comment: that's not what I am asking. Run the same command that your script runs, but not inside your script. run it directly on the command line so that we can see what the output is and try and see why your regexp is not matching of it there is another problem.

Comment: ok, sorry , here is the ouput when I run C:\>ffmpeg.exe -i cisco1.flv
FFmpeg version Sherpya-r10707, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  libavutil version: 49.5.0
  libavcodec version: 51.45.0
  libavformat version: 51.14.0
  built on Oct 11 2007 06:25:25, gcc: 4.2.1 [Sherpya]
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cisco1.flv':
  Duration: 00:08:37.0, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 421 kb/s
  Stream #0.0(und): Audio: mpeg4aac, 44100 Hz, stereo
  Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 960x720, 29.97 fps(r)
Must supply at least one output file

Comment: edit your question and add that (use the code `{}` button to format it), comment formatting completely messes it up.

Comment: Agree to @Mat comments, the problem caused by regexp matching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You match with:

```
if (m!Duration: ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9])!) {
```

But the output is:

```
Duration: 00:08:37.0, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 421 kb/s
```

Notice that there is only one digit after the `.`.

Try:

```
if (m!Duration:\s+([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]?)!) {
```

It will match if there is one or two digits after the `.` (and you should escape `.` in the regular expression, otherwise it matches any single character).

```
$ cat input
FFmpeg version Sherpya-r10707, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
libavutil version: 49.5.0
libavcodec version: 51.45.0
libavformat version: 51.14.0
built on Oct 11 2007 06:25:25, gcc: 4.2.1 [Sherpya]
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cisco1.flv':
Duration: 00:08:37.0, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 421 kb/s
Stream #0.0(und): Audio: mpeg4aac, 44100 Hz, stereo
Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 960x720, 29.97 fps(r)
Must supply at least one output file
$ cat input | perl -ne 'if (m!Duration:\s+([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]?)!) { print $1, "\n"; }'
00:08:37.0
```

Comment: Sorry.. This is giving me the same results.  Let me tel you , I tried my code in linux machine and it worked fine.

Comment: @mac: I changed it just a bit to allow for a possible tab or more than one space. works here with the input you provided - can't help you more than that.

Comment: hey.. thanks.. it worked.. I downloaded a fresh copy and made the changes as you said and it worked.. Thank you soooo much..

Comment: hi mat.. can you resolve this issue         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786443/searching-a-unknown-substring-in-a-string-using-perl