# Perl script to list all the files

Tags: regex, perl, file, download

I have a website where some of the downloadale files are stored.
say the website contains files like

```
GTP-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.123.iso
GTP-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.127.iso
GTP-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.132.iso
GTP-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.136.iso

PRE-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.124.iso
PRE-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.126.iso
PRE-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.127.iso
PRE-UGP-LATEST-5.3.0.130.iso
```

The number of these files will go on increasing day by day with accending version number.

My final goal is to run the script everyday(cronjob)to check if there is any new file added and if yes download all the new files added.

My logic is get the version numbers of all files starting with GTP*(say 5.3.0.123)convert it to (530123) and then compare to get the largest number and then check with the previous downloaded version number which is stored in a local file.If it doesnt match, we download the file with greatest version number that start with GTP

And we do similary with file starting with PRE*

Im poor is regular expression, please help me on this.

Please let me know to list all the files in a link and then write it to a local file. If I know that much then I think I can take it from there

Comment: Are you capable of writing the rest of the script, with the exception of whatever parts you think might require regular expressions?  If so, post that code so we can help you fill in the blanks.

Comment: I know about the downloading part. Please let me know how to do following 1)list all files starting with GTP, 2) get ther version number and remove (dots) in it and compare to get largest. After getting largest version number download the GTP file with largest version number.

Comment: Please let me know to list all the files in a link and then write it to a local file. If I know that much then I think I can take it from there

Comment: The canonical reply is "don't use regex to parse HTML, use a HTML parser" but if the page is machine-generated - and you can post a snippet of the HTML you need to pick apart - maybe you could get away with it. Given that you say you're not good with regex, you should consider Doing It Right, though.

Comment: OP has posted a similar question earlier, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786443/searching-a-unknown-substring-in-a-string-using-perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated:* I would do the following (tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use File::Glob ':glob';

sub by_version {
  my $v_a = $a;
  my $v_b = $b;
  $v_a =~ s/[^\d\.]//g;
  $v_b =~ s/[^\d\.]//g;
  my @version_a = split(/\./, $v_a);
  my @version_b = split(/\./, $v_b);

  for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@version_a); $i++) {
    my $comp = $version_a[$i] <=> $version_b[$i];
    return $comp if ($comp != 0);
  }

  return 0;
}

my @files = bsd_glob('GTP-UGP-LATEST-*.iso');
my @sorted_files = sort by_version @files;
print Dumper(@sorted_files);
```

Comment: where do we provide the website link in this code ? say my link is http://earth.wifi.com/isos/preFCS5.4/upgrade/

Comment: Ahh you meant to parse an HTML site and provide a link to that. Okay, my solution won't work for you.

Comment: Yes I mean parse HTML and list all the words that start with "GTP-UGP-LATEST-" and end with ".iso" . something like GTP-UGP-LATEST-*.iso and write it into a local file

Comment: I still dint get where you provide the link to the HTML. Dont you have to use get($url) ?

Comment: I thought you wanted to list files from a local directory. Parsing HTML with regexes is *not* a good idea however.

Comment: so any idea how to do it with a HTML parser ?

Comment: Then, you should try it. We're here not to do your job.

Comment: sorry, let me know if there is a solution for parsing.. No time to try out new things as of now.

Comment: Come back when you have time.  Doing it right to begin with will save you time in the longrun, and frankly, you could have been done already instead of waiting on us to provide a solution if you just picked a parsing module and read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments... I figured it out...anyway thanks for let me to know about HTML parser, will look into that sometime..

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just rsync from the download directory, since you only want the new ones.